# Error in logic while making a toString() method for a generic queue class

Tags: java, queue, logic

I'm trying to make a `toString()` method for a generic queue that utilizes an `ArrayList`. I'm having some trouble in the for loop that uses a `StringBuilder` to make the String that the `toString()` method returns.

When I try to print one of these objects using `toString()`, I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`.
I think the problem is on line that reads `T element = q.get(front - k);` but I am not really sure.

(The `front` variable references the front of the queue, that being the next number to be dequeued).

```
public String toString() {

    //Create new StringBuilder
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    //If q is empty, return so
    if(isEmpty())
        sBuilder.append("The queue is currently empty" + "\n");

    //else make the string
    else {

        sBuilder.append("The next item to get removed is " + front + ";\n");

        //for loop to create the rest of the list
        for (int k = 0; k < getSize(); k++) {

            //Set the element num, and find the element.
            int elementNum = k + 1;
            T element = q.get(front - k);

            //Print that element
            sBuilder.append("Element " + elementNum + " is " + element + ";\n");
        }
    }

    //return StringBuilder
    return sBuilder.toString();
}
```

This is the method to enqueue

`public void enqueue(T t) {`

```
    //Add to queue
    size++;
    q.add(rear, t);
    rear++;

}
```

This is the method to dequeue

`public T dequeue() {`

```
    //Minus Size
    size--;

    //Set the value to value
    T value = q.get(front);

    //set front equal to null for garbage collection
    q.set(front, null);

    //Update front
    front++;

    //return value
    return value;

}
```

I also have a `int getSize()` Method and a `isEmpty()` Method.

Comment: You mention "error", "problem", and "trouble", but you never specify **exactly** what the issue is that you're seeing.   Are you getting error messages?  Unexpected results?  What, _precisely_, is the code doing (or not doing) that is different from what you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I edited and added the exception my console was giving me when trying to `System.out.println()` the object.

Comment: @leifoftrees Sorry but I am a bit confused. Why are you doing `q.get(front - k)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'd really need to see the full implementation to be sure, but this is how I think it works. Your front and rear both probably start at zero and when you add elements you increase rear, so elements later in the queue have a higher index.

So say we start with an empty queue and add 3 elements. Front will be 0, rear will be 3, and size will be 3. (PS: you don't need a variable for size, you can just use rear minus front). So when you do q.get(front-k), you'd be trying to get the elements at index 0 (okay so far), -1 and -2 (that's where you get the error). You'll want to do q.get(front+k) or q.get(rear-k), depending on which order you want the elements to be printed.

Comment: I implemented `front + k` and its worked perfectly. Thank you.